# Considerations before buying powerline adapter

Tags: powerline-networking

From next week schools will be closed in our country and children will learn from home.

For that I need to extend network to children's room.

To avoid cables going through the house (or drilling walls / attaching cable ducts) I'm thinking about buying a pair of powerline adapters, however - as I've never used them - I'm a bit concerned whether it'll work in our home.

Our house receives electricity through just one pair of cable (230V vs in some house 3 wires for 350V), so that's already good. However there are circuit breakers for different rooms, so I can't avoid to drive the signal through them, is that a problem?

As the two children will also need to attend online classes with video I plan to buy a Gigabit adapter ac wifi. Is it realistic this setup to work correctly?

Shall I expect any interference with other devices? (we've just standard devices like microwave owen, washing machine, dishwasher, TV...)

Comment: I don't know enough about it to provide an actual answer, but often they don't like to cross 'boundaries' between different fuses/RCDs. In my own home, they will work across some rooms [even on separate ring mains], but not across different floors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a realistic setup but breakers might be a problem, so I would only get them if there is a return policy. On my experience, interference on the worst moments has accounted to diminishing around 60-75% of the max speed, which will still leave plenty of bandwidth in a gigabit adapter with a decent connection.

Instead, if the rooms are not that far away I would recommend a WiFi extensor, or even better a Wifi mesh system, which will provide higher speeds and more uniformity across the house.

Comment: Finally I bought a powerline adapter as distance was too big for extender and mesh would've costed much more. The speed is great, however devices switch too slowly between networks. I believe indeed mesh system would be the ultimate solution.